# Apache spark gets stuck when in a loop. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to run a local job. It works for the first couple of loops, then it stops processing at the last chunk. I cannot see why or what is wrong.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("simpleSparkGetsStuck")
        .setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory","4g");


while(true) {

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    // read list to RDD
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    getData(data); //generates a lot of data
    JavaRDD<String> items = sc.parallelize(data, 20);

    // apply a function for each element of RDD
    items.foreach(item -> {
            ... Do some job ...
        }
    });

    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: What exactly does *"stops processing"* mean? It crashes, hangs, becomes slow...?

Comment: Freezes at "INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13) in 817 ms on localhost (executor driver) (19/20)". There is no processing done, "stops" as in : CPU usage is very low.

Comment: Place the context out of the loop. Creating multiple contexts as you are doing might cause the program to behave unexpectedly

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis that is how the issue begun, so I placed it in the loop... either way, same issue occurs.